# JS/ES6: Undefined check on destructuring on a dynamic defined variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm using some destructuring like this based on dynamic data:

```
const {
        groupSku,
        parentGroupSKU,
        orderOriginationId,
        sku,
        quantity,
        partialShip,
        categoryID,
        masterCategoryID,
        siteId,
        assortmentId,
        servicing,
        servicing: { itemServiceTypeID },
        servicing: { style },
        servicing: { text },
        servicing: { serviceQuantity }
    } = item;
```

The following can be undefined -

servicing, servicing: { itemServiceTypeID }, servicing: { style }, servicing: { text }, servicing: { serviceQuantity }

How do check the above `undefined` when assigned to `const` ?
I wanted to check if "servicing" is undefined then rest of under servicing should omitted.

Was getting `y.servicing is undefined` in the console in were an item not having  `servicing`.

Comment: You could use defaults? `{ groupSku = 'something' } = item`?

Comment: then how can assign actual value?

Comment: What do you mean? The default will only apply when the actual value is missing

Comment: I wanted to check if "servicing" is undefined then rest of under servicing should omitted.

Comment: Kindly approve the answer if found helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
let item = {
  masterCategoryID: '<masterCategoryID>',
  assortmentId: '<assortmentId>',
  siteId: '<siteId>',
  someDefinedProp: {
    someDefinedPropChild: '<someDefinedPropChild>'
  }
}

const {
    masterCategoryID,
    siteId,
    assortmentId,

    someDefinedProp,
    someDefinedProp: { someDefinedPropChild } = {},
    someDefinedProp: { someUndefinedPropChild } = {},

    servicing,
    servicing: { itemServiceTypeID } = {},
    servicing: { style } = {},
    servicing: { text } = {},
    servicing: { serviceQuantity } = {}
} = item;

console.log('someDefinedProp:', someDefinedProp)
console.log('someDefinedPropChild:', someDefinedPropChild)
console.log('someUndefinedPropChild:', someUndefinedPropChild)

console.log('servicing:', servicing)
console.log('itemServiceTypeID:', itemServiceTypeID)
console.log('style:', style)
console.log('text:', text)
console.log('serviceQuantity:', serviceQuantity)
```

Comment: here how it will check the "servicing" is undefiend?

Comment: Was getting y.servicing is undefined in the console in were an item not having servicing

Comment: Check the updated code and let me know if you still have any doubts. :)

Comment: Do I need to for servicing? servicing = {} or servicing = '' ??

Comment: You only need to put `servicing: {}` when you intentionally want `servicing`'s value to be an *empty object* instead of `undefined`, you don't need otherwise.

Comment: so my error was on the first level like what I mentioned on the post. servicing is undefined. If the servicing was undefined then the rest of will be undefined that is my objectives.

Comment: My updated answer already solves that issue. You shouldn't be getting any error. Please be a bit more specific if you are still getting errors.

Comment: Now getting "Cannot destructure undefined"

Comment: I had added like bellow --

Comment: const {
        groupSku,
        parentGroupSKU,
        orderOriginationId,
        sku,
        quantity,
        partialShip,
        categoryID,
        masterCategoryID,
        siteId,
        assortmentId,
        servicing: {},
        servicing: { itemServiceTypeID } = {},
        servicing: { style } = {},
        servicing: { text } = {},
        servicing: { serviceQuantity } = {}
    } = item;

Comment: You don't really need to put `servicing: {}`. I presume the error `Cannot destructure undefined` must be from an undefined `item` and not its `servicing` property. Can you please add some more code in your question to help us debug it better.